# PHP single request profile

Tags: php, profiling, xdebug

I want to profile some part of my application to make improvements. The recommended way to do this seems to be to enable xdebug in php.ini but this makes it write profiler stuff on every request which is slow and generates a lot of files.

Constantly enabling and disabling would be annoying though.

What I want is to have something I can run from the command line that will run specific requests to particular URLs and write a profiler report to a specific folder when run but not profile the rest of the time.

Comment: Use Xdebug as you known but use it with trigger. Learn more at https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler look at **Related Settings** section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your php.ini contains:

```
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
```

Now you can profile a single web page using cURL:

```
curl -I http://my-website.local/?XDEBUG_PROFILE
```

Note the XDEBUG_PROFILE query parameter: this is what enables Xdebug's profiler (see the documentation: https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler).

cURL will show us:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 10 Mar 2020 08:45:50 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.2
X-Xdebug-Profile-Filename: /tmp/cachegrind.out.6173
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

The profiler added a `X-Xdebug-Profile-Filename` header for us that contains the cachegrind file, which we can then open in a program such as KCachegrind.

If that header is not present, you're either using a version of Xdebug < 2.6, or the Xdebug profiler is not configured correctly.